# Cloudflare: cURL header get blocked

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I have the problem that cloudflare (PRO = Paid) blocked my php cURL to get header information. I am owner of that site and i have whitelisted my own server-ips.

Here are the code, all other website without CF works less problems:

```
<?php 
$url = "https://domain.tld";

$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // we want headers 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // we don't need body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch);

echo 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode; 
?>
```

What can i do there?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "CF blocked cURL"? What is in the `$output`, what is in `$httpcode`? Or maybe curl is throwing an Exception / triggering an error?

Comment: the content of $httpcode is the http-code ex. 503, it works on all other website without cloudflare but on my own project protected with cloudflare i dont get any response from header, so i think it get blocked somewhere even if i have put my server-ips on whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

In the Cloudflare dashboard, click on the Firewall tab - you can then whitelist IPs in the Access Control window:

[image: Cloudflare IP Firewall]

Note that you need to whitelist the IP which is making the cURL request itself.

For more information, please see: [How do I control access to my site?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-How-do-I-control-access-to-my-site-)

Let us know if you still face issues after setting that up.

Comment: I have whitelisted my server-ips allready on this tab, but there are no change about that.

Comment: Have you tried writing in to supportATcloudflareDOTcom?